# HTTP Range Header Openshift Scalable App

Tags: node.js, http-headers, openshift, haproxy

I have a Scalable Node.JS application on OpenShift that relies on the range header being present. I'm not sure what is removing the header (maybe haproxy?), but I'm wondering if anyone has experience with this and how I can get the range header to come through to my application.

I know for sure that the range header is being sent from the client as it's present on my development server so it's definitely something in OpenShift's stack that's removing the header before it reaches my app.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you reported this as a bug, worth linking here: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1127925

Comment: Good call! I actually switched the application to run on AWS Elastic Beanstalk for now as this was a deal breaker for me, but I should have added the link to the bug.